# Images from a dynamic php gallery to canvas, some advice please

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

I'm looking for some advice on a web app I'm trying to make.

A little flow chart describing my project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr1wu.png

1 Upload folder where new images are being added daily.

2 Thumbnail gallery of the images uploaded
- Thumbs are generated by a simple php script that also creates the gallery.

3 Send any thumb from the gallery to a Canvas.

I figured out all the steps, except for going from 2 to 3.

All the tutorials I have found only deal with drawing an image on Canvas via a client upload, or only focus on drawing a single image where the url is usually located in a .js file.

Two options I'm considering:
- Add a Canvas to a lightbox with the image drawn in it.
- Have a Canvas inside the gallery, and somehow draw the full size image on there.

Is there a javascript library which can do this? (preferably one with a demo)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check this out:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: I did, but I can't find examples on how to deal with multiple image sources.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

2 images in 1 canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Image 1:</p><img id="mysqllogo" width="170" height="115" src="https://www.mysql.com/common/logos/logo-mysql-170x115.png" alt="MySQL Logo">
<p>Image 2:</p><img id="phplogo" width="200" height="120" src="http://php.net/manual/en/images/c0d23d2d6769e53e24a1b3136c064577-php_logo.png" alt="PHP Logo">
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img1 = document.getElementById("mysqllogo");
var img2 = document.getElementById("phplogo");
ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(img2, 125, 45)
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes something like that. But I want to be able to pick and choose which of those images comes on to the canvas, and I need to have some kind of system where newly uploaded images get added to the list of images.

Comment: Maybe you can be a bit more specific.

Comment: Alright, I'll try. Thanks for being so patient with my noobieness :)

How can visitors of my site add 1 or more pics from a thumbnail gallery to a Canvas located on the same page?

The thumb gallery is constantly updated with new pics, so it is not an option to manually include them every time new pics are added.

Example:
A meme generator where users can upload their own pics to a library for others to add text on.